# how to make pair string comparision from csv file in perl

Tags: regex, perl, string, compare

i have a problem with the code to make string pair comparison. my data in csv file as below

```
WorkerId,query,sysa,sysb,Answer.selectedsys

A2ZBU2WW9WHXB7,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
A2ZH0XH25HXD1Y,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel

A1V89RF7V0DCF5,male,lucene-noLen-rel,lucene-noLen-rr,lucene-noLen-rel
AZ92SE5L1P238,male,lucene-noLen-rel,lucene-noLen-rr,lucene-noLen-rr 

A2ZBU2WW9WHXB7,male,lucene-std-rel,lucene-noLen-rr,lucene-std-rel
A1DGNCZZWELLVX,male,lucene-std-rel,lucene-noLen-rr,lucene-noLen-rr
```

the output results should be as below:

```
compare: lucene-std-rel      random     
result: lucene-std-rel-->2           random--> 0        draw (choose both)--> 0 

compare: lucene-noLen-rel    lucene-noLen-rr    
result: lucene-noLen-rel=1   lucene-noLen-rr =1     draw=0

compare: lucene-std-rel lucene-noLen-rel    
result: lucene-std-rel= 1    lucene-noLen-rel=1     draw=0.
```

my code: it seems just count if user choose either sysA, sysB or both without considering the pair of string.

```
for($i=0;$i<@query;++$i) {
if ( $field[1] eq $query[$i] ) {
    if ( $field[4] eq $field[2]) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[4]\n";
    $counta++;
    } 
    if ( $field[4] eq $field[3]) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[4]\n";
    $countb++;
    }
    if ( $field[4] eq ($field[2] && $field[3])) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[4]$field[3]\n";
    $countc++;

}
```

any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
if ( $field[4] eq ($field[2] && $field[3])) {
```

is probably not doing what you expect. It is not equivalent to

```
if ($field[4] eq $field[2] && $field[4] eq $field[3]) {
```

Comment: thanks. i have changed it. another problem is how i want to capture from compare field[2]field[3], after that count the result in field[4]. i have 7 worker, work on each pair of comparision. i want to calculate the majority vote for each pair, for each query.

Answer (score 0):

The '&&' operator returns the last value evaluated.
The '&&" operator first evaluates the left hand operand followed by the right hand operand and returns the right hand operand. 
So in the expression -  ( $field[4] eq ($field[2] && $field[3])), it essentially means you are doing  ( $field[4] eq $field[3] ).

Of course assuming that both the left hand and the right hand operand are true.

As suggested by @mob, you should probably do - ( $field[4] eq $field[2] &&  $field[4] eq $field[3] )

Comment: my code only count for each resultset, left, right and both. the pair is always changed between the query. i didnt get the results as i showed to you in above.